# populate values from parent window in pop up using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page with a link.

```
<a href="PopUp.jsp" target="_blank" id="popUp">View</a>
```

When the link is clicked PopUp.jsp opens in another window.

I would like to populate this window with values from the first jsp.

Example:
Parent.jsp

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="city"/>
<a href="PopUp.jsp" target="_blank" id="popUp">View</a>
```

PopUp.jsp

```
<script>
    function setThis(){
        document.getElementById("pname").value=document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("pcity").value=document.getElementById("city").value;
    }
</script>
<body onload="setThis();">
<input type="text" id="pname"/>
<input type="text" id="pcity"/>
</body>
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: You're trying to reference elements from another page. `document.getElementById("name")` only works if the *current* document contains an element with that `id`.

Comment: Popups have a special property  – `opener`  – which you can use to refer to the "parent" window, but only if the popup was opened using JS.

Comment: Thank you Paul and Teemu. Your answers solved my problem. I hadn't seen it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method and use the object returned by that to access the new window instance. The returned object can be used to access properties and methods of the new window provided it complies with Same origin policy security requirements.

Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your page (If not,you can use vanilla javascript to wire up your click event to your code. use `onclick` event)

```
$(function(){

  $("#popUp").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   var url="url to the new page here";

   var newWindow = window.open(url);

   var pname="read from this page";
   var pcity="read from this page";

   newWindow.setThis(pname,pcity);

  });

});
```

Update your `setThis` to accept these values

```
function setThis(pname,pcity)
{
  .// do something
}
```